# Select Numpy Array of Objects by Objects Attributes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array of objects *Equity*, i.e.:

```
array([ Equity(24, symbol='AAPL', asset_name='APPLE INC', exchange='NASDAQ GLOBAL SELECT MARKET'),
   Equity(26578, symbol='GOOG_L', asset_name='GOOGLE INC', exchange='NASDAQ GLOBAL SELECT MARKET'),
   Equity(5061, symbol='MSFT', asset_name='MICROSOFT CORP', exchange='NASDAQ GLOBAL SELECT MARKET'),
   ...,
   Equity(20513, symbol='LOOK', asset_name='LOOKSMART LTD', exchange='NASDAQ CAPITAL MARKET', ),
   Equity(27133, symbol='WPCS', asset_name='WPCS INTERNATIONAL INC', exchange='NASDAQ CAPITAL MARKET'),
   Equity(27917, symbol='FREE', asset_name='FREESEAS INC', exchange='NASDAQ CAPITAL MARKET')], dtype=object)
```

The object Equity has the attribute **exchange**.

Which is the most concise method to get a subarray containing only Equity objects where **exchange == 'NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE'**?

Thanks!

Comment: When used like this a `numpy` array is basically the same as a Python `list`.  There are few 'vectorized' operations that work on object elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the numpy array is named `equity_array`.

#### Solution 1:

Use list comprehension

```
np.array([eqt for eqt in equity_array if eqt.exchange == 'NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE'])
```

#### Solution 2:

Use Python build-in function `filter`

```
np.array(filter(lambda x: x.exchange == 'NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE', equity_array))
```

Notice that in Python 3 `filter` returns a `iterator` so it should be

```
np.array(list(filter(lambda x: x.exchange == 'NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE', equity_array)))
```